# Primitive Data Types in Dart Lnaguage

Tags: dart, primitive-types

My question is short and simple.
when everything is in dart no matter it is a string, boolean, int, float, or char everything is stored in the object in dart language.
so according to the definition anything which has a reference type(Stored in object) is non-primitive, so is all the above types are non-primitive in the dart, or if these are primitive then what about the definition, anything stored in an object is non-primitive.
also, tell me what are the primitive data types of dart language

Answer (score 3):

If you define "primitive value" to be a non-reference value, Dart doesn't have any.

All Dart values are (references to) object instances that implement either `Object` or `Null`. All can be stored in a variable of type `Object?`.

Some types are more closely supported by the runtime system (like `int`, `double`, `String`, `bool` and `Null`), and for performance and platform interoperability reasons, you are not allowed to have your own classes implementing those. In a sense, those are "fundamental" types (*I* wouldn't say "primitive", but others might).